# Share custom caption label in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, label

I created a custom caption label an use it to insert under all figures in my document.
When my colleague opens the document, he sees the correct text.
However, when he tries to insert another caption, he sees only the "default" word captions (i.e. Figure).

What do I need to do to share the custom labels between different users?